# Assertion error whilst running truffle test

Tags: unit-testing, ethereum, solidity, chai, truffle

I got an error while running truffle test on a smart contract, can anyone help me with this?

```
const KryptoBird = artifacts.require("KryptoBird");

// check for chai
require('chai')
.use(require('chai-as-promised'))
.should()

contract('KryptoBird', (accounts) => {

    let contract
    before( async () => {
    contract = await KryptoBird.deployed()
    })
    
    
    
    describe('deployment', async() => {
        it("deploys successfully", async () => {
            const address = contract.address;
            assert.notEqual(address, '')
            assert.notEqual(address, null)
            assert.notEqual(address, undefined)
            assert.notEqual(address, 0x0)
        })
        it('has a name', async() => {
            const name = await contract.name()
            assert.equal(name, 'KryptoBird')
        }) 

        it('has a symbol', async() => {
            const symbol = await contract.symbol()
            assert.equal(symbol, 'KBIRDZ')
        })

    }) 

    describe('minting', async ()=> {
        it('creates a new token', async ()=> {
            const result = await contract.mint('https...1')
            const totalSupply = await contract.totalSupply()
            assert.equal(totalSupply, 1)
            const event = result.logs[0].args
            assert.equal(event._from, '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000', 'from is the contract')
            assert.equal(event._to, accounts[0], 'to is msg.sender')

            await contract.mint('https...1').should.be.rejected
        })
    })


})
```

this is my code, and when I run it, it gives me an error that I don't understand
this is the error:

```
1 ) Contract : KryptoBird
      minting
         creates a new token :
    AssertionError : expected promise to be rejected but it was fulfilled with { Object ( tx , receipt , ... ) }
```

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jdJga.png)

please help me, I've been stuck on this for a day.

heres my smart contract code, if u could help me
thanks a lot! :

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

import './ERC721Connecter.sol';

contract KryptoBird is ERC721Connecter {

    string[] public kryptoBirdz;

    mapping(string => bool) _kryptoBirdzExists;

    function mint(string memory _kryptoBird) public {
        
        require(!_kryptoBirdzExists[_kryptoBird],
        'Error - kryptoBird already exists');

        // this is deprecated - uint _id = KryptoBirdz.push(_kryptoBird);
        kryptoBirdz.push(_kryptoBird);
        uint _id = kryptoBirdz.length - 1;

        // .push no logner returns the length but a ref to the added element
        _mint(msg.sender, _id);

    }
    

constructor() ERC721Connecter('KryptoBird','KBIRDZ')
{}

}
```

Comment: can u pls share your contract code. some thing is wrong with the contract. (also, pls do not share image when you ask question. )

Comment: I shared it already, I think it's the KryptoBird one

Comment: your solidity code.

Comment: sorry, Im new, is this what u mean?

Comment: No need to be sorry. I answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not you are not adding entry into the `_kryptoBirdzExists` mapping. before you mint, you are checking this condition

```
 require(!_kryptoBirdzExists[_kryptoBird],
```

So after minting, you should be updating the mapping

```
 _kryptoBirdzExists[_kryptoBird]=true;
```

Your test is not failing because you never added the 'https...1' to the mapping so `require` stament was passing so you were minting again

Comment: it removed the other error, but I got this 
"ParserError: Expected identifier but got '1'"

Comment: did you place  `_kryptoBirdzExists[_kryptoBird]=true;` right under `_mint`. it is weird you run the test you did not get that error

Comment: I place _kryptoBirdzExists[_kryptoBird]=true; right under it

Comment: That might be something configuration error. I believe I solved your question